# SQL sum one column over time period grouped by other column

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb

I have a log of purchases during different times of the day. Say that each item is sold x times on a receipt. I want to sum all of the ones sold for each model during each day to get the total for each model.

Some example data:

```
Name      Count Timestamp
----      ----- ----------
Car1        2   2016-05-21 10:23
Car2        1   2016-05-21 11:30
Car1        2   2016-05-21 15:40
Car3        4   2016-08-12 12:03
Car1        2   2016-08-12 14:45
Car3        4   2016-08-12 17:03
```

The result I want to get from this data is how many of each car is sold each day.

```
Name      Count Timestamp
----      ----- ----------
Car1        4   2016-05-21
Car2        1   2016-05-21
Car3        8   2016-08-12
Car1        2   2016-08-12
```

So far I have only managed to do the total sum for each model (using SUM(Count) and GROUP BY Name). But I want to get this for a specific timeframe, each day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just Format your TimeStamp as a Date and then `GROUP BY` it, something like:

```
SELECT NAME, SUM(Count), DATE(Timestamp) AS 'Date'
  FROM table
 GROUP BY NAME, `Date`
```

[Documentation for `DATE` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date)

Comment: `'Date'` is a constant string; don't `GROUP BY` that.  Instead, use backtics.  (I edited it.)